# MySQL select count

Tags: mysql, count

I am trying to count the number of companies that have at least one product from the following query

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM company c
JOIN product p on c.id = product.company_id
WHERE p.is_deleted = 0
AND c.is_customer = 1
AND c.company_type_id = 5
GROUP by c.id
```

So, this shows me a list of all companies, and the count of products for each company.

What I am trying to achieve is a count of companies from the above result.

This can be achieved as follows:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM ( 
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM company c
    JOIN product p on c.id = product.company_id
    WHERE p.is_deleted = 0
    AND c.is_customer = 1
    and c.company_type_id = 5
    GROUP by c.id) AS t1
```

So, this gives me the correct result, but I am just wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing things.

Comment: It seems that you have done a pretty good job here. i see no room for improvement unless you really suffer performance issues

Comment: Surely the above query will always return 1?! You have a `COUNT(*)` which returns a single field, then you `SELECT COUNT(*)` again for a single field...Am I missing something?

Comment: @another: the inner count(*) has a `group by` - it returns one count per company

Comment: Need to take more time in reading things! Missed the `GROUP BY` there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you can simplify it to this:

```
SELECT count(distinct c.id)
FROM company c
JOIN product p on c.id = product.company_id
WHERE p.is_deleted = 0
AND c.is_customer = 1
AND c.company_type_id = 5
```

Comment: Are you not just counting the distinct companies here? Not the distinct products per company?

Comment: @another I think that's what the question is asking for - number of companies with at least one product.

Comment: @anothershrubery: the query will count how many unique company ids are in the result, and the result is filtered to only the companies that have at least one product. very good job @Blorgbeard - i stand corrected

Comment: Yeah, I apologise I read the requirements wrong. Yes Blorgbeard would be correct.